# jquery - animate two elements with one action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to create a parallax effect where images slide over a background, and the background moves too, but only very slightly. Is that possible with jQuery?  I tried referencing both elements by ID with the animation but that isn't working.

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var timer;

                $("#leftarrow").hover(function() {
                    timer = setInterval(function() {slideLeft();}, 50);
                }, function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                });


            $("#rightarrow").hover(function() {
                    timer = setInterval(function() {slideRight();}, 50);
                }, function() {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                });



            function slideLeft() {
                $("img#background").stop().animate({
                    'left': '-=200px'
                }, 50);
                $(".mid").stop().animate({
                    'left': '-=20px'
                }, 50);

            }

            function slideRight() {
                $("img#background").stop().animate({
                    'left': '-=200px'
                }, 50);
                $(".mid").stop().animate({
                    'left': '+=20px'
                }, 50);
            }


            });
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYYDv/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why -1? please help me learn how to post better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an `img` tag for the background, set the image inside a div, and adjust the div accordingly.

Here is my implementation - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/tvjxa/)

Comment: This worked, thank you. So jQuery will not animate an image, has to be within a div? Not totally clear as to why this wouldn't work with just an image.

Comment: The only reason why it didn't work was because your css syntax was incorrect. `#background img` should be `img#background`.

Comment: I only put the image inside a div because it was consistent with the rest of your markup.